# Open file using bash with unix executable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, exec

I have an application which loads using a bash script e.g

/Applications/My.app/Contents/MyExecutable

I can load this using bash like so

"/Applications/My.app/Contents/MyExecutable"

However, I would like to open a file with this executable (a file that was created with the executable and can be loaded)

Im wondering how to do this?

This doesnt seem to work:

"/Applications/My.app/Contents/MyExecutable" "/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyFiletoload.xxx"

Is there any common way of doing this?

Comment: If the application has not been coded to accept a file to open in its run string, there is not a lot you can do. You will need the run string specification: many programs accept a file as the first non-option parameter; others use `-f FileName`; yet others use different parameters, depending on the type or purpose of the file; and some do not look at the run string at all, but rely on a dialogue to specify a file to open. If the application is reasonably well written, `app --help` should summarise the run string; if it's even better written, there will be a manual page `man app`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the problem is that this app used to allow loading of files, but it looks like they are blocked now. Very useful answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in a comment, it all depends on the application. It would need to be written to accept a file as an argument/parameter when running it. There are multiple ways to pass a file into an application, but it depends on how it is written.